# Which privileges i should to set for deleting keys from hive HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: registry, c++builder

I work in c++builder with registry. Anybody know how to set program privileges for deleting keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE?

```
I try to use reg->deletekey();
```

And:

```
RegDelnode(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("Software\\Test"));
```

But not one of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In very broad terms you need to have administrator privileges to write/delete HKLM.

More specifically, you need some combination of the standard DELETE right and the registry-specific KEY_WRITE, KEY_SET_VALUE, KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY rights. And maybe others, depending on exactly what you want to do. A common strategy is to have an administrator assign the appropriate rights for a specific registry key to a specific user, and from that time on the the nominated user can write/delete the key and its values without further recourse to the administrator.

You can write your own administrator tool to assign these rights, or you can use Microsoft or third-party tools. Microsoft provide a tool called subinacl.exe at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=e8ba3e56-d8fe-4a91-93cf-ed6985e3927b&displaylang=en.

To assign rights in an admin tool of your own devising, check out the Windows API functions **SetSecurityInfo** and **SetEntriesInAcl**. To find the specific rights you need, browse the documentation for **RegDeleteKey**.

It's somewhat tricky to get this right, but that's because it's a sensitive and important topic and so I think you just have to roll up your sleeves and get stuck in. For example, the order of ACEs in an ACL is important, and there's a difference between REVOKE_ACCESS and DENY_ACCESS.